# Printing <function at > instead of proper variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

I have a python program that prints a scoreboard but when it prints the output is  instead of printing the correct variable `scoreboard`.

My code is as follows:

```
scoreboard = '\n'.join([
    '┌────────────┐',
    '│     Player           │',
    '│                      │',
    '│         4            │',
    '│                      │',
    '│                      │',
    '│  Computer            │',
    '│                      │',
    '│          5           │',
    '│                      │',
    '└────────────┘'])

score_board = scoreboard

def scoreboard():
    for i, line in enumerate(score_board.splitlines()):
        mvaddstr(12 + i, 1, line)
    endwin()

scoreboard()
```

This is what prints:

```
<function scoreboard at 0x03ACF6A8>
```

Why is it printing the above line and not the `scoreboard` variable?

Comment: Try removing the `score_board = scoreboard` and defining `score_board = 'that long string'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because your redefine two times the variable scoreboard (Function / List).
Try changing the name of the function.